# PHP Replace part of a string before the substring I search for

Tags: php, string, replace, substring

I have a string, for example

"The antelope is hungry today";

I want to search for "hungry" and replace whatever 3 characters are before it with "xxx"  So the end result in this case would be

"The antelope xxxhungry today"

I thought maybe the substr_replace function might work, or maybe combining that with strlen, but I'm not getting it.
Thank you.

Comment: u can use strpos()

Comment: show your efforts(current code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) in combination to get your desired behavior:

```
$str = "The antelope is hungry today"; // str to search

$needle = "hungry"; // str to search for

// returns beginning index of 'hungry' (16 in this case)
$start_index = strpos($str, $needle); 

$result = substr_replace($str, "xxx", ($start_index - 3), 3);

echo $result; // prints : The antelope xxxhungry today
```

See this [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xit6-mz9g) for my working example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use strpos() to find specific words inside strings

```
$value = "The antelope is hungry today";
if(strpos($value , 'hungry ') !== false){
    echo "word found";
}
```

if you found the word you, then you can replace the words you like inside the if condition.

Comment: Right, but I don't want to replace the word I found, I want to replace the 3 chars BEFORE that word

Comment: @chase made it first. Take a look at his answer

Answer (score 0):

Your could use regular expressions

```
$pattern = "/.{3}(?=hungry)/"; 
$string = "The antelope is hungry today";
$replacement = "xxx";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

#### Explanation

- . Match any character
- {3} 3 times
- (?=hungry) followed by hungry

Answer (score 0):

try this function it will work finely and resolve your issue:

```
substr_replace($yourText,"XXX",(strpos($yourText,"partYouAreLookingFor")-3),3);
```

The function **strpos** enable to find the position of the text portion you are looking for. It will be used to define the starting point of the modifcation. the number **3** after represents the number of elements starting for the starting point that will be modified